# Create a gauge chart in svg or css

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need to implement a chart that looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSIUp.png

I tried using  in svg but I'm not able to achieve what I've needed. The code I've used is the following:

```css
svg {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

path.purple {
  stroke: url(#gradient);
  stroke-dasharray: 282;
  stroke-dashoffset: 282;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg style="fill:none; stroke:#81125A" width="400" height="400">

       <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#81125A" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#81125A" />
       </linearGradient>

      <path d=" M  124.58399310102934   183.5  A  79 75 0 0 1 118.30403252765396 121.58238841571327"stroke="#e7e7e8" stroke-dasharray="65,65"></path>

      <path d=" M  123.90504313598774   109.6392784815247  A  79 75 0 0 1 198.51076142578597 71.18269623051319" stroke="#e7e7e8" stroke-dasharray="90, 90"></path>

      <path d=" M  212.11182975237372   73.22782052930026  A  79 75 0 0 1 267.2357170420868 120.34848925057486" stroke="#e7e7e8" stroke-dasharray="75, 75"></path>

      <path d=" M  270.79981248796446   132.97638667498023  A  79 75 0 0 1 259.99579959635764 185.74394481749036" stroke="#e7e7e8" stroke-dasharray="60,60"></path>

</svg>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to look exactly like that? You can get a pretty quick version with [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org).

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("chart");

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [700, 200],
      backgroundColor: ["rgb(133, 13, 123)", "rgb(235, 235, 235)"]
    }, ],
  },
  options: {
    rotation: Math.PI + 50,
    circumference: Math.PI + 0.5,
    cutoutPercentage: 90
  },
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="chart" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I need exactly the same which looks like my image.